# Font Awesome icon borders changed size from v5 to v6

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-6

I thinking about upgrading FA from version 4 to version 6. The size of the borders of icons is unexpected in version 6, so the placement of the characters is shifted in my app. The v6 borders are the expected width, but the heigh is small on many examples (does not surround the whole icon). The borders look as expected in V5 icons. I'm using webfont (not SVG) icons in both cases.

Is there a way to specify the icon image in V6 to get full-size borders?

[V6 icons with small borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMcpc.png)

[V5 icons with normal borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifae5.png)
(the missing icon is "scissors" which does not exist in v5)

Example html...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    
    <!--link href="fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet"-->

    <link href="fontawesome-free-6.4.2-web/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="fontawesome-free-6.4.2-web/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
        <br>
        <br><i class="fas fa-fw fa-question"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-border-all fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder-open fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-save fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-link fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-copy fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-scissors fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cut fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-paste fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-times fa-lg fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-times fa-1x fa-border"></i>
         <i class="fas fa-fw fa-redo fa-border"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

My application is https://spinningnumbers.org/circuit-sandbox/index.html